# creating a rails web site builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web

I'm planning to develope a website builder using ruby/rails. The basic architecture will be as folllows

1 - each website will be given a unique subdomain

2 - web sites main domain will be mapped to this subdomain (Ex: www.mysite.com -> www.mysite.websitebulder.com)

3 - This top level domains (Ex- www.mysite.com might want to use url masking)

4 - I'm planning to use liquid and rails3

5 - I'll be using apache and passenger.

I would like to have your opinion on,

1 - Normally what are the ways of doing something like this (creating a hosted web site builders)

2 - does my approach make sense.

3 - What are the cautions i should take for a project like this

4 - any other comment you all think I should beware of

thanks in advance

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad for a good Stack Overflow question, but there's a Railscasts episode on subdomains in Rails 3 to get you started:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3